# How to properly use 3rd party dependencies with Sublime Text plugins?

Tags: python, dependencies, sublimetext3, python-import

I'm trying to write a plugin for Sublime Text 3.

I have to use several third party packages in my code. I have managed to get the code working by manually copying the packages into `/home/user/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User/`, then I used relative imports to get to the needed code. How would I distribute the plugin to the end users? Telling them to copy the needed dependencies to the appropriate location is certainly not the way to go. How are 3rd party modules supposed to be used properly with Sublime Text plugins? I can't find any documentation online; all I see is the recommendation to put the modules in the folder.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Sublime uses it's own embedded Python interpreter (currently Python 3.3.6 although the next version will also support Python 3.8 as well) and as such it will completely ignore any version of Python that you may or may not have installed on your system, as well as any libraries that are installed for that version.

For that reason, if you want to use external modules (hereafter `dependencies`) you need to do extra work. There are a variety of ways to accomplish this, each with their own set of pros and cons.

The following lists the various ways that you can achieve this; all of them require a bit of an understanding about how modules work in Python in order to understand what's going on. By and large except for the paths involved there's nothing too "Sublime Text" about the mechanisms at play.

> *NOTE:* The below is accurate as of the time of this answer. However there are plans for Package Control to change how it works with dependencies that are forthcoming that may change some aspect of this.
>
> This is related to the upcoming version of Sublime supporting multiple versions of Python (and the manner in which it supports them) which the current Package Control mechanism does not support.
>
> It's unclear at the moment if the change will bring a new way to specify dependencies or if only the inner workings of how the dependencies are installed will change. The existing mechanism may remain in place regardless just for backwards compatibility, however.

All roads to accessing a Python `dependency` from a Sublime plugin involve putting the code for it in a place where the Python interpreter is going to look for it. This is similar to how standard Python would do things, except that locations that are checked are contained within the area that Sublime uses to store your configuration (referred to as the `Data` directory) and instead of a standalone Python interpreter, Python is running in the plugin host.

### Populate the library into the `Lib` folder

Since version 3.0 (build 3143), Sublime will create a folder named `Lib` in the data directory and inside of it a directory based on the name of the Python version. If you use `Preferences > Browse Packages` and go up one folder level, you'll see `Lib`, and inside of it a folder named e.g. `python3.3` (or if you're using a newer build, `python33` and `python38`).

Those directories are directly on the Python `sys.path` by default, so anything placed inside of them will be immediately available to any plugin just as a normal Python library (or any of those built in) would be. You could consider these folders to be something akin to the `site-packages` folder in standard Python.

So, any method by which you could install a standard Python library can be used so long as the result is files ending up in this folder. You could for example install a library via `pip` and then manually copy the files to that location from `site-packages`, manually install from sources, etc.

```
Lib/python3.3/
|-- librarya
|   `-- file1.py
|-- libraryb
|   `-- file2.py
`-- singlefile.py
```

Version restrictions apply here; the `dependency` that you want to use must support the version of Python that Sublime is using, or it won't work. This is particularly important for Python libraries with a native component (e.g. a `.dll`, `.so` or `.dylib`), which may require hand compiling the code.

This method is not automatic; you would need to do it to use your package locally, and anyone that wants to use your package would also need to do it as well. Since Sublime is currently using an older version of Python, it can be problematic to obtain a correct version of libraries as well.

In the future, Package Control will install `dependencies` in this location (Will added the folder specifically for this purpose during the run up to version 3.0), but as of the time I'm writing this answer that is not currently the case.

### Vendor your dependencies directly inside of your own package

The `Packages` folder is on the `sys.path` by default as well; this is how Sublime finds and loads packages. This is true of both the physical `Packages` folder, as well as the "virtual" packages folder that contains the contents of `sublime-package` files.

For example, one can access the class that provides the `exec` command via:

```py
from Default.exec import ExecCommand
```

This will work even though the `exec.py` file is actually stored in `Default.sublime-package` in the Sublime text install folder and not physically present in the `Packages` folder.

As a result of this, you can `vendor` any `dependencies` that you require directly inside of your own package. Here this could be the `User` package or any other package that you're creating.

It's important to note that Sublime will treat any `Python` file in the top level of a package as a plugin and try to load it as one. Hence it's important that if you go this route you create a sub-folder in your package and put the library in there.

```
MyPackage/
|-- alibrary
|   `-- code.py
`-- my_plugin.py
```

With this structure, you can access the module directly:

```py
import MyPackage.alibrary 

from MyPackage.alibrary import someSymbol
```

Not all Python modules lend themselves to this method directly without modification; some code changes in the `dependency` may be required in order to allow different parts of the library to see other parts of itself, for example if it doesn't use relative `import` to get at sibling files. License restrictions may also get in the way of this as well, depending on the library that you're using.

On the other hand, this directly locks the version of the library that you're using to exactly the version that you tested with, which ensures that you won't be in for any undue surprises further on down the line.

Using this method, anything you do to distribute your package will automatically also distribute the vendored library that's contained inside. So if you're distributing by Package Control, you don't need to do anything special and it will Just Work™.

### Modify the `sys.path` to point to a custom location

The Python that's embedded into Sublime is still standard Python, so if desired you can manually manipulate the `sys.path` that describes what folders to look for packages in so that it will look in a place of your choosing in addition to the standard locations that Sublime sets up automatically.

This is generally not a good idea since if done incorrectly things can go pear shaped quickly. It also still requires you to manually install libraries somewhere yourself first, and in that case you're better off using the `Lib` folder as outlined above, which is already on the `sys.path`.

I would consider this method an advanced solution and one you might use for testing purposes during development but otherwise not something that would be user facing. If you plan to distribute your package via Package Control, the review of your package would likely kick back a manipulation of the `sys.path` with a request to use another method.

### Use Package Control's Dependency system (and the dependency exists)

Package control contains a [dependency mechanism](https://packagecontrol.io/docs/dependencies) that uses a combination of the two prior methods to provide a way to install a dependency automatically. There is a [list of available dependencies](https://packagecontrol.github.io/) as well, though the list may not be complete.

If the `dependency` that you're interested in using is already available, you're good to go.  There are two different ways to go about declaring that you need one or more dependencies on your package.

> *NOTE*: Package Control doesn't currently support dependencies of dependencies; if a dependency requires that another library also be installed, you need to explicitly mention them both yourself.

The first involves adding a `dependencies` key to the entry for your package in the package control channel file. This is a step that you'd take at the point where you're adding your package to Package Control, which is something that's outside the scope of this answer.

While you're developing your package (or if you decide that you don't want to distribute your package via Package Control when you're done), then you can instead add a `dependencies.json` file into the root of your package (an [example dependencies.json](https://github.com/wbond/package_control/blob/master/example-dependencies.json) file is available to illustrate this).

Once you do that, you can choose `Package Control: Satisfy Dependencies` from the command Palette to have Package Control download and install the dependency for you (if needed).

This step is automatic if your package is being distributed and installed by Package Control; otherwise you need to tell your users to take this step once they install the package.

### Use Package Control's Dependency system (but the dependency does not exist)

> The method that Package Control uses to install `dependencies` is, as outlined at the top of the question subject to change at some point in the (possibly near) future. This may affect the instructions here. The overall mechanism may remain the same as far as setup is concerned, with only the locations of the installation changing, but that remains to be seen currently.

Package Control installs dependencies via a special combination of `vendoring` and also manipulation of the `sys.path` to allow things to be found. In order to do so, it requires that you lay out your dependency in a particular way and provide some extra metadata as well.

The layout for the package that contains the dependency when you're building it would have a structure similar to the following:

```
Packages/my_dependency/
├── .sublime-dependency
└── prefix
    └── my_dependency
        └── file.py
```

Package Control installs a `dependency` as a Package, and since Sublime treats every Python file in the root of a package as a plugin, the code for the dependency is not kept in the top level of the package. As seen above, the actual content of the dependency is stored inside of the folder labeled as `prefix` above (more on that in a second).

When the dependency is installed, Package Control adds an entry to it's special `0_package_control_loader` package that causes the `prefix` folder to be added to the `sys.path`, which makes everything inside of it available to `import` statements as normal. This is why there's an inherent duplication of the name of the library (`my_dependency` in this example).

Regarding the `prefix` folder, this is not actually named that and instead has a special name that determines what combination of Sublime Text version, platform and architecture the dependency is available on (important for libraries that contain binaries, for example).

The name of the `prefix` folder actually follows the form `{st_version}_{os}_{arch}`, `{st_version}_{os}`, `{st_version}` or `all`. `{st_version}` can be `st2` or `st3`, `{os}` can be `windows`, `linux` or `osx` and `{arch}` can be `x32` or `x64`.

Thus you could say that your dependency supports only `st3`, `st3_linux`, `st3_windows_x64` or any combination thereof. For something with native code you may specify several different versions by having multiple folders, though commonly `all` is used when the `dependency` contains pure Python code that will work regardless of the Sublime version, OS or architecture.

In this example, if we assume that the `prefix` folder is named `all` because `my_dependency` is pure Python, then the result of installing this dependency would be that `Packages/my_dependency/all` would be added to the `sys.path`, meaning that if you `import my_dependency` you're getting the code from inside of that folder.

During development (or if you don't want to distribute your dependency via Package Control), you create a `.sublime-dependency` file in the root of the package as shown above. This should be a text file with a single line that contains a 2 digit number (e.g. `01` or `50`). This controls in what order each installed dependency will get added to the `sys.path`. You'd typically pick a lower number if your dependency has no other dependencies and a higher value if it does (so that it gets injected after those).

Once you have the initial dependency laid out in the correct format in the `Packages` folder, you would use the command `Package Control: Install Local Dependency` from the Command Palette, and then select the name of your dependency.

This causes Package Control to "install" the dependency (i.e. update the `0_package_control_loader` package) to make the dependency active. This step would normally be taken by Package Control automatically when it installs a dependency for the first time, so if you are also manually distributing your dependency you need to provide instructions to take this step.