# unable to load sublime text 3 package

Tags: python, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I am building a custom Sublime Text 3 package and this package has a dependency on jpype python library.  To handle this dependency I built the jpype binary and created this package [in this github repository](https://github.com/rogue-one/st3_jpype). I installed this dependency and I am able to find the st3_jpype.sublime-package available in the package directory as shown below

```
C02D2309MD6R python3.3 $ ls
0_package_control_loader.sublime-package    Package Control.sublime-package         st3_jpype.sublime-package
C02D2309MD6R python3.3 $ find .
.
./Package Control.sublime-package
./0_package_control_loader.sublime-package
./st3_jpype.sublime-package
C02D2309MD6R python3.3 $ vi Package\ Control.sublime-package
C02D2309MD6R python3.3 $ pwd
/Users/myname/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Lib/python3.3
C02D2309MD6R python3.3 $ jar -tf st3_jpype.sublime-package
package-metadata.json
st3_osx_x64/org.jpype.jar
st3_osx_x64/_jpype.cpython-38-darwin.so
st3_osx_x64/JPype1-1.2.1.dist-info/RECORD
st3_osx_x64/JPype1-1.2.1.dist-info/LICENSE
st3_osx_x64/JPype1-1.2.1.dist-info/WHEEL
st3_osx_x64/JPype1-1.2.1.dist-info/entry_points.txt
st3_osx_x64/JPype1-1.2.1.dist-info/NOTICE
...
....
......
```

But when I try to import the jpype package in the sublime text python console I am getting the new module found error

```
>>> import jpype
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'jpype'

>>> import st3_jpype
>>> 
>>> dir(st3_jpype)
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__']
```

How can I make sublime text resolve this dependency without issues?

Comment: Did you try `import st3_jpype`? Also, did you build jpype with Python 3.3?

Comment: Your console output is unclear; did you put `sublime-package` files inside of the `Lib` folder? If so, that's not going to do anything. See [How to properly use 3rd party dependencies with Sublime Text plugins?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61200528/814803) for an overview on your options and how to place the files appropriately.

Comment: @MattDMo i am able to import using st3_jpype but that module is empty and I am not able to access any class/functions defined inside it etc

Comment: @rogue-one Did you format the `.sublime-package` file as a jar or as a Python package? Sublime probably can't find it because it can't interpret `.jar`s from `.sublime-package` files, which are really only ZIP files.

Comment: I didn't format it as a jar .. I used the jar command just list the content of the `st3_jpype.sublime-package`. the st3_jpype.sublime-package is a proper zip file..

Comment: @MattDMo I have updated the question to show you that I am able to import st3_jpype but nothing exists in that imported object ..

Comment: @rogue-one any chance you could post the `.sublime-package` on Dropbox or Google Drive so I can take a look at it?

Comment: @MattDMo sent you the google drive link to SO chat